# How can I parse a txt file using multiple wildcards?

Tags: python, wildcard

The goal is to get just the updated numeric values along with their identifiers while ignoring everything else. I have a CDM.txt file with 1 line of information that gets updated every couple hours and the numeric values all change.

`'MISS_DISTANCE': '18', 'MESSAGE': 'NEED HELP', 'MISS_DISTANCE': '105398', ETC, ETC`

I would like to parse the text file and set the output to variable "Miss Distance". Using that example, I would need to get the following and ignore the rest.

`'MISS_DISTANCE': '18' | 'MISS_DISTANCE': '105398'`

Here is what I have so far.

```
with open('CDM.txt') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
reg = re.compile("'MISS_DISTANCE': '.+',")
```

Not sure what to do from there or if I am even doing the compile correctly. I added the .+ for multiple wildcards since the number can range between 1 to 99999 and a "," at the end because I want it to end there.

Comment: You want one or more digits `\d+`, not one or more of anything `.+`.

Comment: _"since the number can range between 1 to 99999"_ Your example of `'MISS_DISTANCE': '105398'` seems to contradict this assertion

Comment: Please consider upvoting any answer that you found helpful and accepting the answer that is most helpful by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. This is completely optional. I noticed you went ahead with my solution but wanted to allow for floats. You can simply ask and it would be a quick fix on my end!

Answer (score 0):

This opens two files, your file (which I call `blankpaper.txt`) and an `out.txt` file. The latter we will write to. If the file is not too large, we can read in the text of the whole file into memory and make `text` refer to it then use `findall()` from the `re` module to find all matches of the regular expression we compiled. `findall` returns a list of all such matches. We can then use this information however we like, for example, writing to a new file. The regular expression matches `'MISS_DISTANCE:'` followed by 1 or more white-space characters (`\s+`) followed by a `'` followed by one or more decimal digits (`\d+`)followed by a `'`.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"'MISS_DISTANCE':\s+'\d+'")
with open("blankpaper.txt") as f, open("out.txt", "w") as f_out:
    text = f.read()
    m = re.findall(p, text)

    f_out.write(f"{m[0]} ")
    for i in range(1, len(m)):
        f_out.write(f"| {m[i]} ")

print(m)
```

Output of `print(m)`

```
["'MISS_DISTANCE': '18'", "'MISS_DISTANCE': '105398'"]
```

`out.txt`

```
'MISS_DISTANCE': '18' | 'MISS_DISTANCE': '105398'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number is in the range 1 to 99_999, you might want to specify the number of digits :

```py
reg = re.compile("'MISS_DISTANCE': '\d{1,5}',")
```

Don't forget that the last item is not followed by a comma ! You should remove the comma in the regular expression, and add it after your match.

Answer (score 0):

```
def _rows():
    with open("your.txt", 'r') as _file:
        text = _file.read()
        for item in text.split(', '):
            _, sep, word = item.partition(': ')
            if sep and word.strip('\'').isdecimal():
                yield item


print(*list(_rows()), sep=', ')
```

Maybe this is what you need. Using `str.partition` and `str.isdecimal` instead of `re.search` for better performance.